# what does this line of code in php do for directories

Tags: php

i am unable to figure it out that what is being stored in array... can any one please explain it. please explain it in easy way. thank you all
i have tried it from a web and complete code is here

```
<?php
$dhandle = opendir('.');
$files = array();

if ($dhandle) {
   while (false !== ($fname = readdir($dhandle))) {
      if (($fname != '.') && ($fname != '..') && ($fname != basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))) { 
          // this if condition is confusing me
          $files[] = (is_dir( "./$fname" )) ? "(Dir) {$fname}" : $fname; 
          // and the above line too
      }
   }
   closedir($dhandle);
}

echo "<select name=\"file\">\n";
foreach( $files as $fname )
{
   echo "<option>{$fname}</option>\n";
}
echo "</select>\n";
?>
```

here is the line of code which i dont understand

```
$files[] = (is_dir( "./$fname" )) ? "(Dir) {$fname}" : $fname;
```

Comment: `?` is the ternary operator. http://php.net/ternary

Answer (score 2):

It's a ternary statement, equal to:

```
if(is_dir( "./$fname" )){
  $files[] = "(Dir) {$fname}";
} else {
  $files[] = $fname; 
}
```

Which means basically, if the variable contains a directory, add the string (Dir) to the front, otherwise just use the variable.

Answer (score 2):

This is the ternary operater.

```
$variable = (condition) ? true : false;
```

is short for

```
if (condition) {
    $variable = true;
} else {
    $variable = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.` is a reference to the current directory (in Linux the PWD)

`..` is the directory before this one, in the path

`if (($fname != '.') && ($fname != '..') && ($fname != basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])))` means:

If the filename being examined:
  a. Is not the name of the current directory, and 
  b. Is not the name of the parent directory, and 
  c. Is not this file (the script itself)

`$files[] = (is_dir( "./$fname" )) ? "(Dir) {$fname}" : $fname;` means:

1. Add to the array named `$files` EITHER
2. **IF** the file being examined is a directory, add "(Dir) filename"
3. **ELSE** just add "the filename"